# Hilighting the Tab in visual force page after certain amount of time

Tags: visualforce

TestMaster__c   LookUp (TestMaster) // [In Test  Object]//

TAT (Turnaround Time)   TAT__c  Pick List (2 hrs, 3 hrs, 5 hrs)//[in Testmaster object]//

turnaroundtime=test1+test2+....

Var x

if   X >> turnaroundtime

alert (change tabstyle of particular record)

please help me anyone...

Comment: welcome to sfse user10874, could you update your question with some more information and code of what you're trying to build ? Having a better understanding of your question, will make it easier to aswer.

Comment: Hai... i have updated(or modified) the question please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript + jQuery to (with some work) accomplish this.

To use the `setInterval` function to execute another function at a specific time interval see:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693157/jquery-function-setinterval

Then you can write a JavaScript function that searches for the tab element you want to change, and then alter its CSS properties to have the desired effect.  jQuery helps with this part.